# Killing vector field for Witten complex?

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, hodge-theory, equivariant-cohomology

I am reading a classical paper by Atiyah Bott ["The moment map and equivariant cohomology"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.115.9341&rep=rep1&type=pdf).  In paragraph "Relation with Witten complex" (at the very beginning of this paragraph) they claims that “$W_s$ is essentially independent of the metric (so long as $X$ preserves it)”.

**Question**: Why is it important, that $X$ preserves metric?

[image]

Comment: $d_s^2 \neq 0$ for any $X$. It doesn't matter, whether $X$ preserves metric or not. If you consider only $X$ invariant forms, then $d_s^2 = 0$ (and it is still does not matter whether $X$ preserves metric).

Comment: Maybe it turns out that if $X$ does not preserve the metric $d_s^*$ does not send $\mathfrak L (X)$ to $\mathfrak L (X)$?

Comment: @s.harp Do you mean, that $d_s^*$ does not commute with $\mathcal{L}(X)$? It may be an answer.

Comment: In Witten's paper, it seems he uses that $X$ is Killing to show that $(d_s^*)^2=-d_s^2$ and then only much later in one of the calculations. But since the previous equality is not needed for the identification in Atiyah Bott, it seems to me that for that identification only, that $X$ is Killing does not seem to be necessary. However I am certain it will be used in Witten's result.